# Cypher MATCH one pattern or the other

Tags: neo4j, match, cypher

This probably is very simple, but I can't find an answer to this... I have a matching rule that says basically:

```
MATCH (N1:Type1)-[:src]->(P)-[:trgt]->((N2:Type1) OR (N2:Type2))

MERGE (N1)-[:src]->(B:Type3)-[:trgt]->(N2)
```

Obviously that code doesn't work, but it's there to illustrate my problem. So, I want to find the same pattern with the difference being the type of `N2` and in both cases do the same thing in the `MERGE`-part. How can this be accomplished?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how modify your query to test if `N2` has either type:

```
MATCH (N1:Type1)-[:src]->(P)-[:trgt]->(N2)
WHERE N2:Type1 OR N2:Type2
MERGE (N1)-[:src]->(B:Type3)-[:trgt]->(N2);
```

Answer (score 1):

There are however performance ramifications to using the 'where' filter after the match. If we use a match, we can go directly to the relationship type store during the match, which is more efficient. Using the 'where' clause we need to extract all the [:trgt] relationships before filtering, So depending upon your graph (whether there are many other possible node types after the ->[:trgt]) it may be more efficient using the code:

```
MATCH (N1:Type1)-[:src]->(P)-[:trgt]->(N2:Type1)
MERGE (N1)-[:src]->(B:Type3)-[:trgt]->(N2);
MATCH (N1:Type1)-[:src]->(P)-[:trgt]->(N2:Type2)
MERGE (N1)-[:src]->(B:Type3)-[:trgt]->(N2);
```